# Chromium browser will not work when in located on network drive

Tags: windows-7, networking, chromium

I downloaded the Chromiun browser from https://download-chromium.appspot.com/. It seems to work fine without installing it - just unzip the folder and open chrome.exe and everything just works without having to install.

However, if I move the chrome folder onto a networked drive (say, Z:), it stops working. I can open it but cannot navigate to any web pages. Has anyone else come across this problem or found a way around it?

The reason I want to do this is that I want Chrome to be available to everyone on the network without them having to install it. When I want to do an upgrade or something else, if it was all on a network drive I would just have to change one folder, rather than go onto everyone's PCs.

I have noticed that it does work if you put it onto a USB stick and run it from there - why would it work on a USB stick but not a network drive? I'm using Windows 7 by the way...

## Update

I have heard of 'chrome portable' but I would like to avoid using this if possible as it is not an 'official' version...

## Update 2

I tried this on Windows XP and it works fine, so it looks like it is a Windows 7 specific problem. Does anyone know of any Windows 7 security 'features' that might be causing this?

Comment: Use the portable version of Chrome.  That isn't even Chrome but Chromium nor is the correct download website.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm trying to avoid using chrome portable since this is an unofficial version. Actually the download link I got from the Chromium website: http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium

Comment: Upvoted this so poster isn't penalized.  Would like to know why this was downvoted.  What is wrong with this question?

Comment: @CraigAnderson Thanks, it's annoying when people downvote with no explanation!

Comment: @user1578653 Some people think it is OK to downvote without explaining why.  I am not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer - well, sort of. I just started chromium with the command line switch '--no-sandbox' and it suddenly started working properly! Not sure why...

It seems that removing the sandboxing disables a lot of security features. I'm not sure if this will affect me as I plan on locking down the browser so that only my web app can be accessed through it. However, in a 'normal' environment I think I would be right in saying that disabling sandboxing is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't run on a network drive with sandboxing enabled because it defeats the purpose of sandboxing.

Please see the original Chromium issue here -> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103902#c27

So, if you need to run Chrome on a network drive, you'll need to pass the `--no-sandbox` argument while starting Chrome.exe

Note that disabling sandboxing is not recommended for security reasons.